# Select by Lambda Expression And Check Null Value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
public List<CompanyRatingInfo> GetTopCompanies()
        {
            return objectContext.Companies.OrderBy(c => c.Reviews.Sum(r => r.Rating))
                .Select(co => new CompanyRatingInfo()
                {
                    CompanyID = co.CompanyID,
                    CompanyName = co.Name,
                    CreateDate = co.CreateDate,
                    Logo = co.Logo,
                    Rating = co.Rating ?? 0,
                    ReviewsCount = (co.Reviews != null ? co.Reviews.Count : 0),
                    WebSite = co.Website
                }).ToList();
        }
```

ERROR:
**Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.**

How can i obtain `ReviewsCount` with checking co.Reviews != null ?

```
`Company` has many `Reviews` which has `Rating`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `co.Reviews.Count()`. Count is a method.

Comment: How is co.Reviews defined in your model? If it's an ICollection, or IEnumerable, then Count() should return 0 even if there are no Reviews.